# Windows AD: difference between "net use ... /user:" as mere mortal or domain-admin?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions

-

### Dear fellows,

being a plain linux and not a windows guy, today I've been really stunned by an effect with share permissions I've never thought to be possible.

AD domain with a windows 2003 server providing a share which has share-level permissions set (via an AD group). Whoever is not a member of that group *should* not be able to map that share, right?

Right - as long as you're logged in as **mere mortal** on a client PC of this domain and try to map with the credentials of another non-admin user:

```
net use K: \\server\share /user:otherUser Password
```

you'll get "System error 5. Access is denied", because `otherUser` has no share-level permissions.

**Wrong**: as soon as you log into the same client PC with a **domain admin** account, that very same share mapping command succeeds like a charm, even though still done as `otherUser` (which still has no share-level permissions at all)!

So even though the `net use ...` should transfer *only* `otherUser`'s credentials to the server, it seems to also transmit **who** is doing the `net use ...`?

By the way - neither the non-admin nor the domain-admin accounts doing the `net use ... /user:otherUser` commands had share-level permissions, if that explains anything...

Am I right in guessing that share-level permissions do not apply to domain admins, even though their `net use ...` is done as a mere mortal "otherUser"? That's my only idea why this is as it is...

Confused regards

Comment: Go to \\server, open Computer Management, look at that share, and check what user ID is mapped, if it's otherUser or the domain admin's account.

Comment: If the domain admin user already had a connection to any share on the server, perhaps one reestablished automatically from a previous session, the /user flag will be ignored.